# How can I restrict the data fetching by URL?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, graphql, aws-amplify

I'm making a static website with NextJS and Amplify. (+ react, typescript etc)

When I'm using dynamic routing like `/projects/[id]`,
It works well on my local but gets some problems after the deployment (after I upload the build files to S3 for static hosting) 
Because the NextJS make http fetch request on the web by the route.

For example, when someone access to `example.com/projects/1234`,
it call a GET request to `example.com/projects/1234` automatically.
And because there are no APIs like that, it returns 404 and do not show the detail page.

In the NextJS document, it says

> FAQ > Why does Next.js have its own Router?  
>  ... It supports shallow routing which allows you to change the URL without running data fetching methods

But I don't want to fetch the data by URLs... 
**Q. How can I restrict this feature?**

FYI) I tried 'trailingSlash: true` in the nextConfig with some search results on web, but no luck.

 Below is my next.config.js

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */

const nextConfig = {
    reactStrictMode: true,
    images: {
        domains: [
            "some-name.s3.some-region.amazonaws.com",
        ],
    },
    trailingSlash: true,
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

p.s. nextJS version is 12.1.0

Answer (score 0):

It's my fault.

I must use 'Link' of NextJS instead of the 'a' tag.

After compared my another project with this one, I updated some 'a' tag as 'Link' and it started working fine...